# Recordset count number in VBA

Tags: vba

Is there a way to get the number of rows of recordset without using the movelast method in VBA? If I try to use the movelast method, the function will stop as i am using the UDF.

Comment: You mean rs.RecordCount ? ' Here rs -> recordset

Comment: Yes I mean get number of recordset without using recordset.count

Comment: Rs.recordcount will returns numbers of rows in the recordset rs.. what else u r looking ?

Comment: If the `.Count` is all you need then you don't really need a `recordset` object for it. Construct your query using a `COUNT` function

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you have to [open the Recordset using `adOpenStatic` or `adOpenKeyset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using `adOpenStatic` will pull the entire Recordset into memory, so it's not a good idea if your application doesn't need to process the entire recordset, you need to view changes made by other users, or if it's too big to fit into memory. On the other hand, processing the `Recordset` can be much faster because it doesn't have to hit the database for each record.

`adOpenStatic` example:

```
' dbConnection is an ADODB.Connection object
rs.Open "source", dbConnection, adOpenStatic
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
```

`adOpenKeyset` example:

```
rs.Open "source", dbConnection, adOpenKeyset
' note: LockType adLockOptimistic may be required for particular databases
' rs.Open "source", dbConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Upon reviewing BzKnt's answer, it appears that another option to gain access to `RecordCount` is to set the `CursorLocation` to `adUseClient`.

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "source", dbConnection
```

Also note that this is dependent on the database and driver you are using. Some of these methods may not work for all types of databases.

Comment: how do i get number of recordset ?

Comment: @Jack. oh, really, how can u get it? -_-

Comment: `adopenstatic` is not in the docs as of 2020. There is `rs.movelast` which moves the cursor to the last row. This should work with `recordcount`. The sql way would be: `SELECT Count(*) FROM " & tab1`

Comment: @Timo it's still there, it's one of the values that the [CursorType enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortypeenum?view=sql-server-ver15) parameter can take. `SELECT COUNT(*)` works too of course, and can be a more clear alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Article here http://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html explains the issue very clearly.
Use VBA to get the correct number of records in a Recordset object
Issue involves the cursor used.

In short add this after setting:
    rs = New ADODB.Recordset

```
' Client-side cursor
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in a working example:

'Query a closed excel workbook and assign a column to a array.

```
Sub TestADO()
    Dim MeArr() As Variant

    MeArr = ADOLoader ("C:\Closed_Workbook.xlsx", "Sheet1", "Column One")

    Debug.Print LBound(MeArr), MeArr(LBound(MeArr))
    Debug.Print UBound(MeArr), MeArr(UBound(MeArr))

End Sub

' SubIDCol is the column header
Function ADOLoader(strSourceFile As String, SheetName As String,         SubIDCol As String) As Variant
    Dim RowPlace, f As Integer
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, sql As String
    Dim ACount As Integer
    Dim SubIDArray() As Variant
  
    sql = "Select  [" & SubIDCol & "] from [" & SheetName & "$]"  

    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strSourceFile & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
        Set rs = .Execute(sql)
    End With
    
' If you wanted the Headers:  
'         For f = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
'            On Error Resume Next
 '           .Cells(r, c + f).Formula = rs.Fields(f).Name
' Debug.Print rs.Fields(f).Name
'            On Error GoTo 0
'        Next f
    RowPlace = 0

    ACount = rs.RecordCount - 1
    ReDim SubIDArray(rs.RecordCount - 1)

        On Error Resume Next
        rs.MoveFirst
        On Error GoTo 0
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For f = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            On Error Resume Next
                SubIDArray(RowPlace) = rs.Fields(f).Value
                RowPlace = RowPlace + 1
                
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next f
            rs.MoveNext
       Loop
   
    '---Clean up---
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

Debug.Print "Lower bound of array = " & LBound(SubIDArray)
Debug.Print "Upper bound of array = " & UBound(SubIDArray)

    ADOLoader = SubIDArray()

End Function
```