# VBA: Could not find Installable ISAM (Works in some computers and others don't)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, connection, adodb

everyone!

My company is creating an excel file that connects to SharePoint for a client. And it works fine in my machine and in the VM of the client's company. But when we try to run the code on the laptop of the client, We get this error. (Could not find installable ISAM)

```
Sub executeSQLList(sql As String, list As String)
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim connString As String

    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://mysite;LIST=" & list & ";"

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open connString
    conn.Execute sql
    conn.Close

    Set conn = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

I checked the permissions on Sharepoint and it seems ok. I also checked the code bellow and it works fine.

```
Function ConnectToExcelSheet(sql_query As String) As Object
    Dim conn As New ADODB.CONNECTION
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connString As String
    
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820663/recordset-count-number-in-vba
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                 "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES'"
    
    conn.Open connString
    rs.Open sql_query, conn  
    Set ConnectToExcelSheet = rs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Function
```

How can i solve that? My other guess is in the version difference between my excel and the client's excel.

Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong - it's been several years since I saw that error - but I think it was to do with MS Access being installed on my machine but not all?

Comment: Indeed we have Access on our machines but the client's laptop doesnt have Access on his machine and can't install Access (company's policy). 

But I don't connect to Access at all and there is no Access file being used by the excel macros. (i don't know if Excel uses access on the background to make the connections)

Comment: I can only assume it's some kind of driver that comes with Access that you're utilising when you reference `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. **Perhaps someone else on here can advise the best way to resolve this.** Sorry I can't help more, when I hit this issue I got them to install Access and the problem went away.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much, CLR!

Seems like they could use some functions without Access before, but I'm having trouble understanding this problem yet.

Comment: @CLR, i was searching on the web and perhaps [Microsoft 365 Access Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9) can help me with this problem. What do you think? Is it worthy a try?

Comment: Definitely worth a try!